# Mimic the email app controls

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to emulate the 'Edit' button in the email app with the same functionality with the checkboxes and delete button when pressed. I can only think of really complex ways to do this, can somebody nudge me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the ways you have thought of and discounted? Can you include them in your question or people might waste time writing them in answers.

Comment: Pushing to a new view, altering commitEditingStyle, loading new table cells with the checkboxes in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use table view editing, a sample code is available in developer site.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011189

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it; I don't have sample code but you asked for a nudge.

- You need to have a custom subclass of UITableViewCell if you haven't already.
- Override `setEditing:animated:` in your subclass. Shrink your content view in from the left and slide in a custom button which will serve as your checkbox indicator (if the cell is in editing mode).
- this button should be linked to selecting and unselecting the row in the table
- add a toolbar to the bottom of the tableView to hold the delete etc buttons - this will then act on the rows that are in your selection.

If you also want swipe to delete you will have to keep track of whether you have set a cell to editing via swipe or via the tables edit button. This can be done by comparing the editig state of the cell and the table - in swipe to delete, the table is not in editing mode, but the cell is.